# My print line is not workng

Tags: java, netbeans

Ok so I have a problem where my program's string characters doesn't want to change.

Eg. This is my code here

```
 System.out.println("~~~~~WELCOME~~~~~");

      do{
          do{
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter item code");
              System.out.print("#");
            itemCode = br.readLine();
            itemCodeCorrect = isItemCodeCorrect(itemCode);

            }while(!itemCodeCorrect);

          do{


            System.out.println("\nPlease enter item description");
            itemDesc = br.readLine();

            itemDescCorrect = isItemDescCorrect(itemDesc);



             }while(!itemDescCorrect);


          do{

          try{
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter item weight");
            itemWeight = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());


          }catch(NumberFormatException ex){


              System.out.println("\n" +ex +"\nInvalid input. Item must be in a number format. Please try again");
              }  

          }while(itemWeight == 0);






          do{
              try{
            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the item price");

            itemUnitPrice = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                 }catch(NumberFormatException ex){

                  System.out.println("\n" +ex +"\nInvalid input. Item must be in a number format. Please try again.");
                                                  }

            }while(itemUnitPrice == 0);

Allitems = new Items(itemCode, itemDesc, itemWeight, itemUnitPrice, quantity, Total, TotalCost, TotalWeight);
v.add(Allitems);
```

but when I run my program the changes I made in the print line does appear when I run it.

OUTPUT-----------------

```
~~~~~WELCOME~~~~~

Enter item code
#kza

Enter item description
peas

Enter item weight
2.2

Enter item price
$
```

Comment: Completely unclear to me

Comment: You'll need to provide some code before we can help you.

Comment: Please provide the code of the complete class you are running.

Comment: We can't see your computer screen. Help us help you by providing code.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ is that better?

Comment: You are not running the code you think you are. Your code has `Please` but your output doesn't.

Comment: There's no obvious reason I can see why the code you supplied is printing the incorrect lines. Are you perhaps running an older version of your code? A different project?

Comment: probably I made a new project and copied everything over

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you're not seeing output then it'd be:

- You've not compiled it after making the change.
- You're not running what you think you're running.

It's not immediately obvious what's supposed to change, so I'd double check these first.